# How to make Validation.GetHasError() return the correct value for DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with input validation and I want to disable a button if it contains validation errors. I check for such errors using the following code:

```
private void sequenceGrid_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This method is called on any click outside the current cell
        ((DataGrid)sender).UnselectAllCells();
        if (HasError(((DataGrid)sender)))
        {
            ((dynamic)DataContext).DatagridsValidated = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ((dynamic)DataContext).DatagridsValidated = true;
        }
    }

private bool HasError(DataGrid dg)
    {
        /*bool errors = (from c in
                           (from object i in dg.ItemsSource
                            select dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(i))
                       where c != null
                       select Validation.GetHasError(c)).FirstOrDefault(x => x);
        return errors;
        */

        for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridRow row = GetRow(dg, i);
            if (row != null && Validation.GetHasError(row))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    public static DataGridRow GetRow(DataGrid grid, int index)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null)
        {
            // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
            grid.UpdateLayout();
            grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
            row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }
        return row;
    }

private void sequenceGrid1_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += mouseClick;
    }

private void mouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        HitTestResult hitTestResult;
        hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(sequenceGrid1, e.GetPosition(sequenceGrid1));
        if (hitTestResult == null) // Click outside the datagrid
        {
            sequenceGrid1.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
            try
            {
                sequenceGrid1.Items.Refresh(); 
            }
            catch { } // Edit mode still open if there is invalid input
        }
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= mouseClick;
    }
```

**The problem is that after editing,** `Validation.GetHasError()` **returns the incorrect value. E.g., I need to click two times in the DataGrid for this method to return the correct value.** I mention that the commented code gives the same result.

**How can I make Validation.GetHasError() return the correct value for the DataGrid?**